# MongoDB fails with SymInitialize error unless there is a very large Page File in Windows

Tags: mongodb, virtualisation, windows-server

I'm wondering if someone can help with a MongoDB/page-file issue we seem to experience as our database increases in size over time. Every now and then MongoDB will crash on a particular node in our replica set and it won't start again until we significantly increase (double is safe) our page file size. Currently, the page file is 42GB. We are running MongoDB as a 3 node replica set and each node is running on a Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machine in Azure. Each server has 3.5 GB of memory. MongoDB is version 2.6.5.

I've seen the posts below, which are related, and I understand that MongoDB uses memory mapped files and presumably virtual memory helps with that when we haven't got lots of RAM. What I don't understand is:

***Why is MongoDB requiring so much memory on start-up (>32GB page file for a 131GB database) and with a relatively small working set (~100MB)? Presumably it can swap out the files as it needs, especially with a page file this large, so why is MongoDB crashing?***

Here are the posts I've found so far:

[mongodb memory usage is going high even if only insertions are made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14134109/mongodb-memory-usage-is-going-high-even-if-only-insertions-are-made)

and this one

[SERVER-10044](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-10044) which explains why Mongo crashes and implies VM's are worse

Thanks in advance for any help.

To provide more context we are using MongoDB to log data, so most of the collections are written to but rarely read from, with the exception of a few small collections (100MB total) which are subject to constant reads and writes. The data is stored in a single Mongo DB database, the stats for which are shown below (db and collection names modified):

```
    "db" : "MyDatabase",
    "collections" : 854,
    "objects" : 243025868,
    "avgObjSize" : 541.2304596809423,
    "dataSize" : 131533002252,
    "storageSize" : 172592721920,
    "numExtents" : 7268,
    "indexes" : 1934,
    "indexSize" : 27824138048,
    "fileSize" : 210284576768,
    "nsSizeMB" : 16,
    "dataFileVersion" : {
            "major" : 4,
            "minor" : 5
    },
    "extentFreeList" : {
            "num" : 3,
            "totalSize" : 110592
    },
    "ok" : 1
```

The working set appears to be around the 100 MB mark, as illustrated below:

```
   "workingSet" : {
           "note" : "thisIsAnEstimate",
           "pagesInMemory" : 20874,
           "computationTimeMicros" : 26236,
           "overSeconds" : 876
   },
```

The log file output on the secondary that most recently failed is as follows (this occurred during start-up although the first time it failed was during normal operation):

---

> 2014-11-25T09:25:17.833+0000 [rsBackgroundSync] replSet syncing to:
>   10.1.6.71:27017 2014-11-25T09:25:17.833+0000 [rsBackgroundSync] replset setting syncSourceFeedback to 10.1.6.71:27017
>   2014-11-25T09:25:17.849+0000 [rsSync] replSet still syncing, not yet
>   to minValid optime 54744561:c 2014-11-25T09:25:18.286+0000 [rsSync]
>   replSet SECONDARY 2014-11-25T09:26:01.590+0000 [conn21] serverStatus
>   was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after
>   backgroundFlushing: 0, after connections: 0, after cursors: 0, after
>   dur: 0, after extra_info: 0, after globalLock: 0, after indexCounters:
>   0, after locks: 0, after network: 0, after opcounters: 0, after
>   opcountersRepl: 0, after oplog: 10451, after recordStats: 10451, after
>   repl: 10451, at end: 10451 } 2014-11-25T09:26:01.590+0000 [conn21]
>   command admin.$cmd command: serverStatus { serverStatus: 1, oplog: 1 }
>   keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:65 reslen:4028 16764ms
>   2014-11-25T09:26:31.155+0000 [DataFileSync] flushing mmaps took
>   15022ms  for 115 files 2014-11-25T09:26:47.501+0000 [conn5]
>   serverStatus was very slow: { after basic: 0, after asserts: 0, after
>   backgroundFlushing: 0, after connections: 0, after cursors: 0, after
>   dur: 0, after extra_info: 0, after globalLock: 0, after indexCounters:
>   0, after locks: 0, after network: 0, after opcounters: 0, after
>   opcountersRepl: 0, after oplog: 4791, after recordStats: 4791, after
>   repl: 4791, at end: 4791 } 2014-11-25T09:26:47.501+0000 [conn5]
>   command admin.$cmd command: serverStatus { serverStatus: 1, oplog: 1 }
>   keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) r:88 reslen:4028 7674ms
>   2014-11-25T09:27:06.350+0000 [repl writer worker 6] **VirtualProtect
>   for m:/mongodb/data/MyDatabase.72 chunk 21220 failed with errno:1455
>   The paging file is too small for this operation to complete.** (chunk
>   size is 67108864, address is 14b90000000) in mongo::makeChunkWritable,
>   terminating 2014-11-25T09:27:06.350+0000 [repl writer worker 6]
>   MyDatabase.RC_PUR_11_456754 Fatal Assertion 16362
>   2014-11-25T09:27:06.615+0000 [repl writer worker 6] Stack trace
>   failed, **SymInitialize failed with error 3765269347**
>   2014-11-25T09:27:06.615+0000 [repl writer worker 6]
>   MyDatabase.RC_PUR_11_456754  2014-11-25T09:27:06.615+0000 [repl writer
>   worker 6]
>
> ***aborting after fassert() failure

Comment: I would suggest to try this: If you can't add more RAM, separate the swap partition from the database data. Reduce then the swap to 2xRAM and start the mongo. If you face the same issue try to increase swap IOPS rather than add more swap, and retry.

Comment: Hi, the page file exists on a separate drive to the database already (basically its on its own dedicated drive). Is that what you mean? We can increase the RAM but it is double the cost for a VM with double the memory in Azure which is costly, especially for a replica set. Many Thanks.

Comment: Yes that what i mean. It may sound like a cliché , but have you optimized all your statements?

Comment: As far as I can tell our reads and writes are all optimized. I haven't run 'Explain' on every query but we're using the MMS service to monitor things and it indicates there are no BTree accesses that weren't in memory i.e. no misses which I'm assuming is an indication that our indexes are optimal. The reply below seems to indicate this is  normal behaviour (the page file being so large).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Windows, in a worst case scenario, your pagefile size might have to be set to the size of your data files + physical memory size.  So if your data files take up 50GB on disk, the rough guidance, in your case, is to set pagefile size to 53.5GB.  This will improve with MongoDB 2.8 release since the new storage engine does not rely on virtual memory services provided by the OS.
On a related subject, your memory size of 3.5GB sounds very low.  Take a look at the Hard Page Faults per second under the Resource Monitor -- if the number is in hundreds, you need to dramatically increase your memory size

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. We know about the memory being low, unfortunately there is a significant cost penalty in Azure should we want an instance with a larger amount of memory, especially when configured as a replica set. The working set does appear small as far as we can tell though (~100MB), although I don't know how that relates to RAM and the mapping of files i.e. if each MongoDB file is 2GB does it want to map that entire 2GB file into RAM then? Or just portions?

Comment: You have mentioned a lot of writes -- its possible that its not the data, but journaling thats causing issues. You can try to experiment by reducing the journal flush/write  times interval -- this will flush out fewer dirty pages, but more often.  Also, every time you write, its a DB level lock -- you can try breaking up your 854 collections into multiple databases -- fewer locks, less congested writes.

Comment: Hi, we'll give that a try. The locking shouldn't be an issue as the process is single threaded and thus there should rarely be concurrent writes. I think your explanation of the size is fair and explains why our page file is getting so large. Hard page faults are less than 10. We're not actually seeing a performance issue which is validated by the MMS stats, its just the file being so large I couldn't understand. Thanks again.